# How could I exit from do-while loop?

Tags: c++, exit-code

I have these block of codes that belong to a NIM subtraction game. The thing that I would like to implement is that user is going to be able play the game as long as he/she wants. Simply if user enters 999 program will exit, otherwise user will be playing until he/she enters 999. Here is my block of codes. I am not sure that I make a logical mistake or I need to add some specific exit code. Thanks for your time and attention.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {

int total, n;
while(true){
cout << "Welcome to NIM. \nEnter 999 to quit the game!\nPick a starting total: ";
cin >> total;
if(total==999)
break;

    while(true){
    //pick best response and print results.
    if ((total % 3) == 2)
    {
        total = total - 2;
        cout << "I am subtracting 2." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        total--;
        cout << "I am subtracting 1." << endl;
    }
    cout << "New total is " << total << endl;
    if (total == 0)
    {
        cout << "I win!" << endl;
        break;
    }
    // Get user’s response; must be 1 or 2.
    cout << "Enter num to subtract (1 or 2): ";
    cin >> n;
    while (n < 1 || n > 2)
    {
        cout << "Input must be 1 or 2." << endl;
        cout << "Re-enter: ";
        cin >> n;
    }
        total = total - n;
        cout << "New total is " << total << endl;
    if (total == 0)
    {
    cout << "You win!" << endl;
    break;
    }
    }
    }
  return 0;
    }
```

Comment: TL;DR; _'How could I exit from do-while loop?'_ Using a `break;`, `return;` or even `exit();` statement??

Comment: The expression `'999'` is a *character literal* (a multi-character literal even, which are extensions in *some* compilers), and `total` is an integer variable. Any normal compiler would have given you plenty of warnings on the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are modifying `total` inside the loop. Just test after `cin>>total` at the beginning if `total==999` and `break` if `true`, i.e.

```
if(total==999)
    break;
```

and replace the `do-while` loop by a `while(true){}`

Comment: Thank you for your time. I added if loop exactly how you posted. It gave error the line that if-break on. The error says break statement is not in the loop or in switch statement.

Comment: It should work if you added the code immediately after the first `cin >> total` at the top of your code... Did you replace the outermost `do-while` loop by a `while(true){ ... }`?

Comment: I added if-break loop right after cin>>total. I replaced the do-while loop as well

Comment: Don't understand why it's not working, can you post your whole code (modified) again?

Comment: vsoftco I just added the codes the way you explained above on the main area. take look at that please. thank you for your time.

Comment: You should enclose everything in a `while(true){ ... }` loop, immediately after `main(){`. See the edit I made to your code.

Comment: BRILLIANT! THANK YOU SO MUCH.You have made me saved a lot of time for debugging. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the do-while loop you are trying to compare character literal '999' with variable total that has type int.

```
}while(total!='999');
```

Though this code is valid its result can be something else than you are expecting. Values of character literals with more than one symbol are implementation defined. 
You have to write

```
} while ( total != 999 );
```

Also if the player will enter 999 you start to play with him though you have to exit the game.

So in my opinion it is better to use while loop. For example

```
while ( true )
{  
   cout << "Welcome to NIM. \nEnter 999 to quit the game!\nPick a starting total: ";

   cin >> total;

   if ( total == 999 ) break;

   // ...
}
```

Comment: I tried codes above it is sort of working but after first input program starts repeating itself from the beginning.

Comment: @Mister T.  i do not understand what you are talking about. If you are not satisfied by the logic then change it. What is the problem?!

Answer (score 0):

you have to do three corrections in your code to make it right

first you have to check if  total is equal to 999, then break in your do loop just after getting the total from user

second - you have to put same condition in your first while loop

and lastly - instead of while(total!='999') u shall write while(total!=999) because it is integer